# How can I count results from one into a group with different conditions? Linq query

Tags: sql, linq, count

```
 select 
        count(pat.ID) as PatientEmail,
        count(a.ID) as AlaEmails,
        count(t.ID) as TrusteeEmails,
        count(s.ID) + 1 as SpecialistEmail
    from [dbo].[Users] as u
    left join [dbo].[Patients] as pat
    on u.ID = pat.ID and u.Email != 'email@gmail.com'
    left join [dbo].[Patients] as a
    on u.ID = a.ID and u.Email = 'email@gmail.com'
    left join [dbo].[Trusteehips]as t
    on u.ID = t.Trustee_ID
    left join [dbo].[Specialists] as s
    on u.ID = s.ID and u.Email != 'email@gmail.com'
    where u.Active = 1 and u.Deleted = 0

    public class UserEmails
    {   
        public int PatientEmail { get; set; }
        public int AlaEmails { get; set; }
        public int TrusteeEmails { get; set; }

    }

public ActionResult ReportByEmail()
        {
            var res =  from u in context.Users
                       join p in context.Patients  
                       on u.ID equals p.ID into pGroup
                       join t in context.Trusteeships
                       on u.ID equals t.Trustee.ID into tGroup
                       select new UserEmails
                       {
                           PatientEmail = pGroup.Count(g => g.Email != "email@gmail.com"),
                           AlaEmails = pGroup.Count(g => g.Email = "email@gmail.com"),
                           TrusteeEmails = tGroup.Count()
                       };

            return View(res);
```

I tried to write this Linq code but it didn't work!
My count result is not shown in one row, I wrote code with same syntax (Group.Count()) and it worked fine, but here it didn't work!

Comment: *it didn't work* isnt' very much of an explanation....... please specify: did you get **no results** at all? Or did you get results, but the **wrong ones**? Did you get an error - if so: *what* error???

Comment: I get result but wrong

Comment: i wont the same result as SQL query but i wrong somewhere